# Complicated sql query, take column data and insert it into another table based on criteria

Tags: sql

I've a task at hand, which is clearly beyond my mysql skills :) I'm learning though...

I've two tables.

```
1. import
2. users
```

import contains allot of columns, such as id, user_id, user_email ...
users contains user_id and user_email

I need to migrate users content to import. Specifically I'm missing user_id in import. But it contains user_email.

So I need to think of a statement, where I match user_email from two tables and update import table with user_id from a match.

So far I've this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_email, i.user_email FROM users u, import i WHERE i.user_email = u.user_email;
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you can directly update table `import` by joining it with `user`.

This is in `MySQL`.

```
UPDATE `import` a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_email = b.user_email 
SET     a.user_id  = b.user_id
```

For `SQL Server`

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.user_id  = b.user_id 
FROM    [import] a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_email = b.user_email
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match users depending on their address make sure they are unique, then you can join them like this:

```
UPDATE import
        SET import.user_id = users.user_id
    FROM import
    INNER JOIN users ON import.user_email = users.user_email
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; that would work; you may want to select other fields as needed. You can also use a JOIN statement; and then you can decide what to do with the user table; are you inserting ? updating ?

I think standard SQL supports INSERT INTO SELECT, not sure about update, but your DBMS may have a SQL extensions supporting it ...